# Create Zapier Trigger

Tags: php, triggers, zapier

After I created the trigger, I need it to use one field, for example
`user_id` (NOT REQUIRED).

I set next URL in:
`Polling: URL` = `http://example.com/api.php?action=list_photos&user_id={{user_id}}`

When I execute a test request - the Zapier gets a list with the status 200.

But when I save the zap - I get 500 error, that my api does not respond.

When I opened the monitoring section, I see the following picture:

A GET request was sent with the following parameters
`action=list_photos&user_id=%7B%7Buser_id%7D%7D&api_key=:censored:32:a8ab235721:`

It turns out when authorizing it uses the wrong parameters for the GET request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where does the `user_id` data come from? When setting up your trigger fields, you should have a "Dynamic Dropdown" ([more info here](https://zapier.com/developer/documentation/v2/trigger-fields/)) that references another trigger that fetches the data. Example:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I think it will help.